# VS2017 ASP.NET Core Web Application

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

Just installed VS 2017 and wanted to start a new ASP.NET Core Web Application - under Templates Visual Basic it shows

Windows Classic Desktop |
Web | 
Cloud | 
Extensibility | 
Test |
WCF

Opening Web it only has the options for MVC or Web Forms

Under Visual C# there is an option for .NET Core - what am I missing? Where did they hide the VB template for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update: [.NET Core 2.0 allows](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/08/14/announcing-net-core-2-0/) to use Visual Basic to develop .Net Core apps.

> **Support for Visual Basic**
>
> *In addition to supporting C# and F#, 15.3 now also supports using Visual Basic to develop .NET Core apps. Our aim with Visual Basic this
>   release was to enable .NET Standard 2.0 class libraries. This means
>   Visual Basic only offers templates for class libraries and console
>   apps at this time, while C# and F# also include templates for ASP.NET
>   Core 2.0 apps. Keep an eye on this blog for updates.*

For starting here is a tutorial for [building a Visual Basic Hello World application with .NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/vb-with-visual-studio).

---

ASP.NET Core 1.1 still doesn't have support for VB compiler. You may monitor progress by this [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/587) in dotnet/cli repo.

Comment: Looks like that was closed last November - have marked your reply up and as the answer, but quite amazed that the full release is still about as good as the proverbial chocolate fire guard. There were comments about RC not having this, but that it would be fixed before VS was released

Comment: The full release is a mess. Even the basic core web application templates are broken in C#

Comment: damn...so VB.Net  will not be supported in Core 2.0?

Comment: @JoshYates1980 actually you can use VB with .NET Core 2.0, have updated post